# transform keys and values with an array as one of them

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby hash

```
a = {
  7 => [1469, 2283],
  5 => [1469, 5464],
  3 => [7561],
  6 => [7952, 8114],
  4 => []
}
```

and would like to get the keys that a number shows up in as a value

```
 b = {
   1469 => [7,5],
   2283 => [7],
   5464 => [5]
   ...  
 }
```

How would I do this? I'm sure there's some super slick way of getting it done.

Comment: Off the top of my head, there's no built-in method that can do this. But a simple `each_with_object` (or `reduce`) should do the job.

Comment: [`Hash#invert`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert) looks potentially useful, but it overwrites repeated keys instead of aggregating them.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane, you seem to be answering a question that wasn't asked. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CarySwoveland My comment had three goals: **1.** Save answerers of this question the time they might spend exploring why they can’t just write `#invert` as their answer. **2.** Potentially guide someone to an answer incorporating `#invert`, if I overlooked some Ruby feature that would make it aggregate repeated keys. **3.** Help any future searchers who find this question but don’t need to aggregate repeated keys, in which case `#invert` might be exactly what they want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
a = {
    7 => [1469, 2283],
    5 => [1469, 5464],
    3 => [7561],
    6 => [7952, 8114],
    4 => [1469, 2283], 
    2 => []
}
```

Use a default value of a new array in `b`:

```
b=Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }
a.each{|k,v| v.each{|n| b[n] << k} }
```

Or include the object creation with [each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
b=a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |(k,v), h|
    v.each{ |e| h[e] << k } }
```

Result `b` is:

```
{1469=>[7, 5, 4], 2283=>[7, 4], 5464=>[5], 7561=>[3], 7952=>[6], 8114=>[6]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `#each_with_object` to iterate over the original hash and the values stored in each array and build up a new hash based on it.

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  v.each do |val|
    h[val] ||= []
    h[val] << k
  end
end
```

Result:

```
{
  1469 => [7, 5], 
  2283 => [7], 
  5464 => [5],
  7561 => [3],
  7952 => [6],
  8114 => [6]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[@dawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74708152/1978251) is the way I would go

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |(k,v),obj| 
 v.each{|e| obj[e] << k} 
end
```

But here are a few other options: (a lot of allocations though)

`Array#product` and `Hash#merge`

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),obj|
  obj.merge!(v.product([[k]]).to_h) {|_,o,v| [*o,*v]}
end
```

`#map` then `#reduce`

```
a.map {|k,v| v.product([[k]]).to_h }
 .reduce {|memo, h| memo.merge(h) {|_,o,n| o.concat(n)}}
```

This works too (don't ask questions)

```
a.map {|k,v| v.each_with_object(k)}
 .reduce(&:+)
 .group_by(&:shift)
 .transform_values(&:flatten)
```

Comment: One more to add to your growing collection: `a.flat_map { |k,arr| [k].product(arr) }.group_by(&:last).transform_values { |a| a.map(&:first) }`.